# Change body background-color with select options input js

Tags: javascript, html

I want the body's background-color to change depending on selected option value and textContent.

```
select.addEventListener('input', function() {
  for (let i = 0; i < select.length; i++) {

    text = select.options[i].text;
    value = select.options[i].value;

    if (value == "Turquoise") {
      body.style.backgroundColor = value;
    } else if (text == "Sun Flower") {
      body.style.backgroundColor = value;
    } else if (text == "Pumpkin") {
      body.style.backgroundColor = value;
    } else if (text == "Alizarin") {
      body.style.backgroundColor = value;
    } else if (text == "Emerald") {
      body.style.backgroundColor = value;
    } else if (text == "Peter River") {
      body.style.backgroundColor = value;
    } else {
      body.style.backgroundColor = "#bdc3c7";
    }
  }

});
```

The problem's when i choose an option the background-color changes only once by checking the last `else if` statement. I tried with  `input` and `change event` and nothing changes.

`options[i].value` contain colors name in hexadecimal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need to iterate all the options you should get the selected option and retrieve the value to assign to the background, and use the `change` event for the select-dropdown see a demo below

```js
var select = document.querySelector("#my-select");
var body = document.body;
select.addEventListener('change', function() {
  var options = this.options;
  var selectedOption = options[options.selectedIndex];
  body.style.background = selectedOption.value;

});
```

```html
<select id="my-select">
  <option value="#add8e6">Blue</option>
  <option value="#90ee90">Green</option>
  <option value="#ffc0cb">Pink</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Working perfectly. Thanks !